# (Vala) unowned string return type with string templates

Tags: vala

```
unowned string to_string () {
    int x = 0;
    return @"$x";
    // error: Return value transfers ownership but method return type
    // hasn't been declared to transfer ownership
}
```

doesn't work. and works without `unowned`.

Why? I saw:

> Literal strings in Vala are always owned by the program module itself
>   - in https://chebizarro.gitbooks.io/the-vala-tutorial/content/properties_ownership.html

In contrast to normal string literal, string templates is not `owned` by the program module? or I have misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String templates are not literal strings.

Literals can be calculated at compile-time, so the compiler simply includes a copy of the string in the compiled program.  String templates, OTOH, generally cannot be known at compile-time (imagine if you were passing `x` in as a parameter, or getting it from an instance or global variable), so memory is allocated on the heap and the contents of the string are calculated at run-time.

To put it another way, string templates are basically syntactic sugar for a call to `string.printf` (or, from C's perspective, `g_strdup_printf`).

Answer (score 2):

A string template is automatically "invoked" when you use it.

So while the actual template literal might be owned by the program module the resulting string will be a normal owned string (in a temporary variable).

So the result of a string template is not owned by the program module, but by the method it resides in. Thus the compiler message is correct.

Answer (score 2):

String templates are a short hand for concatenating strings and variables. So your program can be thought of as the equivalent of:

```
void main () {
    string a = example ();
}

unowned string example () {
    int x = 0;
    return "" + x.to_string ();
}
```

The string template calls the `to_string ()` method for you. The above example produces the same error. Maybe the error message isn't too helpful, but you need to consider why you are returning an unowned string.

Making a string unowned turns off Vala's memory management for the string. This may be relevant if a constant was being returned, but in your example the string is being created at run time and so is allocated on the heap. This means you want to use Vala's memory management. Generally you should let Vala use its default settings for memory management.